# quantmod display weekly indicator on daily chart

Tags: r, quantmod, quantitative-finance, technical-indicator

I am trying to display the daily and weekly RSI on the daily charts but have no success

```
getSymbols('JNUG')
chartSeries(JNUG, subset = 'last 4 months', dn = 'red', TA = 'addRSI(n=14); addLines(h = c(30, 70), on = 2, col = "red"); addTA(RSI(Cl(to.weekly(JNUG)), n =2))')
```

I also tried the following:

```
chartSeries(JNUG, subset = 'last 4 months', dn = 'red', TA = 'addRSI(n=14); addLines(h = c(30, 70), on = 2, col = "red")')
addTA(RSI(Cl(to.weekly(JNUG)), n =14))
```

The weekly RSI does not appear on the plot. Can someone help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you plot the weekly points, NA values are filled in between on the merge to the original daily data.  The weekly RSI plot wants to join together points and NAs as a line plot, but no line is drawn where there are NAs, no line gets drawn in the end.

Try this:

```
chartSeries(JNUG, subset = 'last 4 months', dn = 'red', TA = 'addRSI(n=14); addLines(h = c(30, 70), on = 2, col = "red"); addTA(RSI(Cl(to.weekly(JNUG)), n =2), type = "p")')
```

[image]
Or, if you want lines instead, try this (see lowest `add_TA` call):

```
library(quantmod)
chart_Series(JNUG, subset = '2016-11/')
add_RSI(n= 14)
v <- to.weekly(JNUG)
add_TA(merge(xts(order.by = index(JNUG)), RSI(Cl(v))), type = 'p')
#na.spline interpolates between points smoothly.  Could also use fill = na.locf (produces a step function), etc ...
add_TA(merge(xts(order.by = index(JNUG)), RSI(Cl(v)), fill = na.spline), type = 'l')
```

which produces this:

[image]

EDIT: One way to add horizontal lines on `add_TA` subplots:

```
chart_Series(JNUG, subset = '2016-01/')
add_RSI(n= 14)
v <- to.weekly(JNUG)
# Note: na.locf does not introduce 'lookforward bias' in visualised technical indicator plots, while na.spline does.
add_TA(merge(xts(order.by = index(JNUG)), RSI(Cl(v)), fill = na.locf), type = 'l')
low_rsi <- 30 
hi_rsi <- 70
xrsi_low <- xts(order.by = index(JNUG), x = rep(low_rsi, NROW(JNUG)))
xrsi_hi <- xts(order.by = index(JNUG), x = rep(hi_rsi, NROW(JNUG)))
add_TA(xrsi_low, col = "purple", type = 'l', on = 3, lty = 2)
add_TA(xrsi_hi, col = "purple", type = 'l', on = 3, lty = 4)
```

[image]

Comment: amazing! how do you put rsi horizontal lines though on the third?

Comment: @geodex See the edit.  Use the `on` argument (on = 1,2, or 3) to choose which plot panel to add additional curves too.

Comment: Cheers @FXQuantTrader